# Can Upnp or DLNA stream audio from server to multiple renderers at the same time?

Tags: upnp, dlna

I would like to know if it is possible for upnp/dlna protocol to stream audio from a single media server to multiple media renderers at the same time. Does the protocol allow this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it depends on what you mean with "at the same time". It is possible to access the same media by two different DMPs. However, each of them is creating a new stream, means twice the traffic. UPnP and thus DLNA as well is using HTTP as primary streaming protocol. RTP unicast and multicast streams are also considered but mostly not implemented by the manufacturers because it is not mandatory. So, multicast streams aren't well supported.

Additionally, some servers might implement some limitations when accessing a file or media, f.e. when you have a TV tuner or something else which provides exclusive access to a specific media (tv channel). Then, you can access this media only once at a time.

Comment: +1. Could maybe also mention that if the o/p is looking for synchronised playback across several renderers, this isn't possible via UPnP:AV services

Comment: @simonc Can you elaborate on the "isn't possible" -- is it a technological limitation? something in the DLNA (or UPnP) spec? something else?  I'm also very interested in implementing synchronization -- but I don't want to send myself on snipe hunt :-)

Comment: @TomH UPnP specs for a MediaRenderer device don't include any APIs to support synchronisation.  To do this properly, you'd need ways to start multiple renderers in synch then keep them synchronised (coping with transient network errors, slight variances in clock rates, etc.).  You could approximate a solution by just iterating round a set of renderers, telling all to start playing then repeat for the next track etc.  This won't be synchronised but also won't be terrible.  You could allow other renderers to join mid-track using seek commands; the accuracy of this will likely be pretty poor.

Comment: @simonc thanks a bunch for the explanation.  I agree that the "all renderers start now" solution will perform poorly.  I'm hoping that I can improve on this by simple network latency measurement to minimally get rendering to begin on all devices synch'd.  Keeping them in synch will be another challenge.  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, in UPnP specification there is mentioned synchronised playback, but I'm not sure how widely supported it actually is and it's not clear how to ensrue it with "pull" scenarious and read-ahead buffers. See section 5.1 in this document http://www.upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-AVArchitecture-v2-20101231.pdf